# ¿ como puedo recuperar valores de un EditTextPreference?

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

Estoy trabajando con Preferencias en **android** y tengo un problema, tengo un fragmento que es un PreferenceFragment, en ese fragmento tengo varias opciones una de ellas al dar clic me abre un cuadro de dialog con un campo para colocar texto dentro como muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar clic en la opción de cambiar usuario muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como puedo recuperar el texto que ingrese en ese **EditTextPreference** para posteriormente guardarlo como nuevo nombre de inicio de sesion: el codigo es el siguiente:

**Este es el layout del fragmento:**

```
<PreferenceCategory>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="opcion1"
        android:summary="Da clic aqui para cambiar el nombre de usuario que fue registrado."
        android:title="Cambiar usuario" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory>

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="opcion2"
        android:summary="Da clic aqui para cambiar el nombre de usuario que fue registrado."
        android:title="Cambiar contraseña" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory>

    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="opcion3"
        android:summary="Deseas rescibir notificaciones?"
        android:title="Notificaciones" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

y este es el código del **fragmento**:

```
package com.example.enriq.persistencia_en_android_enrique_espinosa;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConfiguracionesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.configuraciones);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String nomreusuario = preferences.getString("opcion1", "");

    if(nomreusuario != null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"El nuevo nombre de usuario es: "+nomreusuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Kike, cuando guardes un valor en el EditTextPreference opcion1 este valor sera guardado y lo obtendrás al salir y regresar a tu aplicación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener los valores de preferencia, si estas usando un `PreferenceFragment` lo puedes realizar de esta forma obteniendo el archivo de preferencias:

`SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

y posteriormente el valor por medio de la key definida, como ejemplo obteniendo el valor del `EditTextPreference` con `android:key="opcion1"`

```
String valor = pref.getString("opcion1", "");
```

Para un `SwitchPreference` es un poco diferente ya que en realidad obtienes un valor `boolean`, un ejemplo usando  `android:key="opcion3"` :

```
boolean valorSwitch = pref.getBoolean("opcion3",true);
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta resolvio mi problema ahora ya puedo intentar guardar el nuevo nombre

Comment: Excelente Kike.